# How to make an odoo field to be null in condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I want to make the barcode field in product.template is equal of null if I select the type = "service".
 Here is what I done but it's not working correctly.

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('product.template')
def onchange(self, values, type, barcode):
        if type not in ('consu'):
            return super(barcode, self).unlink()
```

Because, sometimes some user write a barcode and the change the type to service and we need to make the barcode to be empty on change the field type.

Answer (score 0):

The onchange function should be triggered by the change of type field. What you are trying to do is wrong.

```
    @api.onchange('type')
    def onchange_type(self):
        if self.type == 'service':
            self.barcode = False
```

This function gets triggered by the change of type field. If the type field value is service then the barcode field becomes null.

Also if you are doing Odoo development, I would recommend you to go through this doc - https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/